# HTML: order of divs and a tags for href

Tags: css, html, href

I'm busy with HTML and CSS and got stuck with this.
I have created a button with :hover and :active options, which is centered on the page. Clicking on this button needs to lead to a website.

My HTML is:

```
<div>
<a href="website"><div id="button">Text</div></a>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 0.5em 0.8em;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Myriad Pro, Source Sans Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ff4700;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ff4700;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease;
    transition: all .1s ease;
}

#button:hover {
   background-color: #ff4700;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid white; 
}

#button:active {
    background-color: #cc3900;
    }
```

The problem lies in the fact that the whole width of the page is clickable at the height of the button and not only the button itself that is 150px wide and is centered on the page.

I think I have my divs mixed up and it needs other formatting and precedence, but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help!

P.S. First time on StackOverflow, sorry if I formatted something wrong.
Edit: P.P.S. Thank you everyone for your reactions, never thought so many would take their time to help! A couple of methods worked, but this was easiest to incorporate.

```
<div>
<a href="website" style="display:block" id="button">Text</a>
</div>
```

Again, thanks!

Comment: Question looks good, formatted well :)   I see the same behavior you are describing using Firefox.

Comment: Its not valid to put a block level element (your div) inside an `<a>` tag.  You probably don't even need your `<div>`, you can just add the id `button` to your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help.

```
<div>
<a href="website" style="display:block" id="button">Text</a>
</div>
```

instead of wrapping the link around a block make the link be the block.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I think a couple of other methods worked too, but this was the easiest one to incorporate.

Comment: I would add display:block to the #button style sheet instead of doing it as an inline style, only placed in inline to highlight the change.

Comment: Your answer was sufficient, do I need to change anything for other browsers or is just using your suggestion good? I'm not very familiar with the best formatting and uses of different tags.

Comment: Displaying anchor tags as blocks works in all browsers, even non standard portable ones. Wrapping blocks with inline tags is discouraged by some in academy; Changing to wrapping blocks with blocks is what academics recommend.

Comment: What is the difference in displaying the anchor as a block, if I may ask?

Comment: anchors&lt;a&gt; by default are inline like &lt;span&gt; which don't support backgrounds ect. But any tag can be displayed as a block, &lt;div&gt; by default is a block. I normally change anchors to blocks to make buttons out of them with backgrounds and centered text.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `margin: auto;` and `display:block;` to the `a` instead of the `button`.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/yGKjq/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64auf/)

This happens in Chrome and FireFox but not in Opera, because of the rendering of the `<a>` element. If you change the display for `a` to `display:inline-block;` and put `text-align:center;` to the parent `<div>`, it will work.

Comment: The solution is great, but it should be noted that this problem does not exist only in Chrome.   I see the same behavior using Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, I only tested Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<div id="button"><a href="website">Text</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<a href="website" id="button">TEXT</a>
</div>
```

Then use your css to center the div.
This should help!

Answer (score 0):

I would re order the HTML and change the CSS a bit. Put the `<a>` inside of the `<div>`.
Add the new class, and style to your taste.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6tzb6/

**HTML**

```
<div>
<div id="button"><a href="website.com">Text</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#button a {width:150px;height:100px;display:block;}
```